# Paperclip processors for new instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm struggling a lot with papperclip and custom cropping.

I'm using lambda for styles and a custom processor like the code below.
But when I run `User.new(user_params)`, `a.instance` is an instance of `User`, but empty, with none of the values passed by `user_params` like `width`, `top` or `left`.

After saving, the data is there, but cropping won't work because it appears paperclip ignores what is the instance before saving.

```rb
  has_attached_file :image,
    styles: lambda {|a| {
      croped: {processors: [:cropper],
         crop_w:a.instance.width,
         crop_x:a.instance.left,
         crop_y:a.instance.top}
    }
  },
  default_url: "/images/:style/user.png",
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

I can run `image.reprocess!`, but this can't be the right way, images would be processed twice.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Paperclip processes the image on assignment instead of on save, so the order of assignment matters. If you're assigning `image` before `top`, Paperclip will process the image right after you assign `image` to User and at that time `image.instance.top` will be empty as `top` hasn't been assigned yet.

So you need to make sure your `user_params` has `top`, `left` and `width` before `image`. Assuming `user_params` returns a `ActionController::Paramters`, you can simply change the order of attributes on `permit`, eg.

```
params.require(:user).permit(:top, :left, :width, :image)
```

If you don't want to depend on hash order, you can also remove `image` from the parameters and assign it to the User instance separately.